# Joining 4 tables in linqToSql

Tags: linq-to-sql, join

I have 4 tables and need to write a linq query to pull information from all tables!

Here is the table structure:

Printer:

- printerID
- PrinterName

Template:

- TemplateID
- TemplateCategoryID
- TemplateName

TemplateCategory:

- TemplatecategoryID
- TemplatecategoryName

Data:

- DataID
- PrinterID
- TemplateID
- CreatedDate
- IsProcessedDate

The information I want is:

PrinterName, TemplateCategory, TemplateName, Data-CreatedDate, Data-IsprocessedDate.

I'm all new to linq and cannot recognize the way to solve this. Much appriciated if anyone has any comment on this.

Thanks alot, Finn.

Comment: setup the primary/foreign keys in the DB you'll not need to write a single Join statement

Answer (score 2):

with some assumptions, add your context reference:

```
from d in Data
join t in Tempalte on d.TemplateID equals t.TempateID
join tc in TemplateCategory on t.TemplateCategoryID equals tc.TemplateCategoryID
join p in Printer on d.PrinterID equals p.PrinterID
select new
{
    p.PrinterName,
    tc.TemplatecategoryName,
    t.TemplateName,
    d.CreatedDate,
    d.IsProcessedDate
}
```